# Why is formatting for blocks of text showing up weirdly?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I was wondering if you could help me with something.

I want to write a menu for one of the scripts I'm working on. Currently, my script is:

```
echo "########################################"
echo "#               Script tasks           #"
echo "#                                      #"
echo "#   1 Show running processes           #"
echo "#   2 Show logged in users             #"
... (continued)
echo "########################################"
```

However, when I run this inside of my script, for some reason some of the `#` signs at the end of the line get either indented into the box, or pushed further out, resulting in the right side of the box looking very bad and not well thought-out. I would like the right side of the box to look even (i.e., actually like a box).

I'm using Bash on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and gedit as my text editor.

Comment: Apologies if this is obvious and you've already checked it, but are you using a fixed-width font in gedit? And when you run this script, are you using a fixed-width font for your terminal output? Because what you describe (the # signs not lining up) sounds *exactly* like what would happen if you're using a proportional-width font somewhere.

Comment: Another possibility is that you've got some tabs in the white space sections of the lines.  Those might expand differently in your editor compared to the shell.

Comment: I'm using a fixed-width font, but I'm not sure about the tab expansion. What do you mean by that?

Comment: Tab characters in the shell mean "jump to the next tap stop", which by default is every 8 characters. In text editors, sometimes the default is 8 characters per tab stop, and sometimes it's 4, because most coders who like using tabs for indentation prefer 4-space indents. So if there's a mismatch between what gedit thinks a tab means, and what your shell thinks a tab means, then any tabs in your source code might look weird in the shell. If you're trying to line things up right, **don't rely on tab characters** as they might mean something different on your users' systems.

Comment: The tab lead is the most likely one, I think. Just a side note: if you want to avoid all these `echo` commands, you can also use the `here document` construct (http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).

Comment: when you do not want to replace the tabs, you can use `| expand -8` (tabsettings are often for 2, 3 or 8 characters). Of course space-tab can be different from tab.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't your question, but the way to do menus in a shell script is with the `select` command

```
# an array with the menu choices
choices=(
    "Show running processes"
    "Show logged in users"
    "..."
)

# define the prompt
PS3="What is your choice? "

# display and get user input
# select is an infinite loop: `break` when you've done something successfully
select choice in "${choices[@]}"; do
    case "$choice" in 
        "Show running processes")
            some code here
            break
            ;;
        "Show logged in users")
            some code here
            break
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Please select a number from the menu."
            # do not break, select will re-display
            ;;
    esac
done

# if you need the choice afterward, you still have it
echo "$choice"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! This is a better solution than using a while loop and a case function as my menu system. However, is there any way to format select so it can look different?